# How to collect values of object properties into a list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, chart.js

I have Json response in this format:

```
[
    {
        "date__month": 8,
        "price__sum": 999.0
    },
    {
        "date__month": 9,
        "price__sum": 999.0
    },
    {
        "date__month": 10,
        "price__sum": 888.0
    },
    {
        "date__month": 11,
        "price__sum": 777.0
    }
]
```

I need to collect all the `price__sum` into an Array `data = [...price__sum]` so I can use it to create chart.

How to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use map method

```
var data=[
    {
        "date__month": 8,
        "price__sum": 999.0
    },
    {
        "date__month": 9,
        "price__sum": 999.0
    },
    {
        "date__month": 10,
        "price__sum": 888.0
    },
    {
        "date__month": 11,
        "price__sum": 777.0
    }
];
var mapped=data.map(i=>i.price__sum);

console.log(mapped)
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the array you have and push the `price__sum` values onto a new one.

```js
let originalArray = [{
    "date__month": 8,
    "price__sum": 999.0
  },
  {
    "date__month": 9,
    "price__sum": 999.0
  },
  {
    "date__month": 10,
    "price__sum": 888.0
  },
  {
    "date__month": 11,
    "price__sum": 777.0
  }
]
let newArray = [];

originalArray.forEach((item)=> newArray.push(item.price__sum));

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Won't you need to parse it first if it's JSON?